# Ntlm-authentication against basicHttpBinding WCF service, using Claims

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, ntlm, claims

This specific claims-authenticated environment happens to be SharePoint. SharePoint has its own http modules which enforce the claims authentication. Unauthenticated access will result in a set of options for claims based authentication (such as Ntlm and forms).

A WCF service client obviously has no idea what to do with the 403-message SharePoint returns. Ideally it would do the Ntlm auth sequence against the url "/_windows", which will yield a 401 challenge, then pass the resulting federation cookies to the WCF service.

This can't be the best practice way of dealing with multiple-auth-option Claims based services, but I'm unable to dig up any good resources on the subject. Is the basicHttpBinding futile? What are my options at this point?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using claims with sharepoint you should use Windows Identity Foundation (WIF). See: http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/SVC26

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Kerberos in this scenario and the ws2007FederationHttpBinding binding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675190.aspx